# Get combinations of words lists

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to write a small script (bash or python) that would give combinations of word lists that would output in  formats as follows.

```
List 1 | List 2 | List 3
Like   | Big    | Trucks
Hate   | Medium | Cars
       | Small  |
```

and would return results similar to the following

```
Like
Hate
Like Big
Like Medium
Like Small
Like Big Trucks
Like Big Cars
Like Medium Trucks
Like Medium Cars
Like Small Trucks
Like Small Cars
Hate Big
Hate Medium
Hate Small
Hate Big Trucks
Hate Big Cars
Hate Medium Trucks
Hate Medium Cars
Hate Small Trucks
Hate Small Cars
Big Trucks
Big Cars
Medium Trucks
Medium Cars
Small Trucks
Small Cars
Trucks
Cars
```

Notice how the words stay in the same order of the lists that they came from.

Comment: "I'm trying to write a small script". Show it to us!

Comment: "Notice how the words stay in the same order of the lists that they came from" - Shouldn't your output list follow the pattern **Big -> Small -> Medium** then?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I just edited it.

Comment: you also seems to have misplaced the single **Hate** word :)

Comment: yes, shouldn't it follow all the like?

Comment: why are Trucks and Cars at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for can be done very easily in python using the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module.

```
import itertools

list1 = ['Like', 'Hate']
list2 = ['Big', 'Medium', 'Small']
list3 = ['Trucks', 'Cars']

sub23 =  [' '.join(x) for x in itertools.product(list2, list3)]
sub12 = [' '.join(x) for x in itertools.product(list1, list2 + sub23)]
res = list1 + sub12 + sub23 + list3
print res
```

Output:

```
['Like',
 'Hate',
 'Like Big',
 'Like Medium',
 'Like Small',
 'Like Big Trucks',
 'Like Big Cars',
 'Like Medium Trucks',
 'Like Medium Cars',
 'Like Small Trucks',
 'Like Small Cars',
 'Hate Big',
 'Hate Medium',
 'Hate Small',
 'Hate Big Trucks',
 'Hate Big Cars',
 'Hate Medium Trucks',
 'Hate Medium Cars',
 'Hate Small Trucks',
 'Hate Small Cars',
 'Big Trucks',
 'Big Cars',
 'Medium Trucks',
 'Medium Cars',
 'Small Trucks',
 'Small Cars',
 'Trucks',
 'Cars']
```

Ps: the logic behind this distribution is "strange" to say the least. May be you could have better answers by providing the real logic behind it :)

Comment: This also produces e.g. `Like Trucks` which OP doesn't appear to want.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, you are right it does not match the output at all but the OP's expected output does not seem to make sense either

Comment: hmm, indeed it doesn't :) I wasn't trying to give the exact answer cause it looks like OP's expected output has some flaws. I'll update my answer

Comment: I haven't tried the updated version that Samy has posted yet. Howevever 'Like Trucks' would be allowed but 'Trucks Like' Wouldn't. It was difficult to explain this in words at 3am. I'm going through the generated results right now, but I think we've got it.

Comment: Can you step us through the logic here? I'm new to python (but not to programming) and especially new to itertools. BTW, the first version of your code is what was needed. Thank you!

Comment: how would I modify the script to accomodate 5 lists?

to answer the question of what this is being used for, it's to help crate long tail key phrases for seo.